# Where should I ask theoretical computer questions?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure where to ask questions about theoretical stuff. I don't want to get down-voted for asking at the wrong place. Also what is the difference between programmers.stackexchange and stackoverflow? Are you supposed to use both for different types of questions?

Comment: The MSO post that answers it - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/213963

Comment: Thank you Michael. I found my answer using the link.

Comment: Please remember that you can always ask question about what site it belongs on in chat (either P.SE's [chat] or [CS.SE](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2710/computer-science)'s - TCS doesn't have an active chat room last I checked)

Answer (score 1):

[CSTheory.StackExchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)

From their [help center](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> What topics can I ask about here?
>
> Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange is a Q&A site for
>   professional researchers in theoretical computer science and related
>   fields. We welcome research-level questions in theoretical computer
>   science (TCS).
>
> What do you mean by "research-level question"?
>
> Although there is no black-and-white distinction between
>   research-level questions and non-research-level questions, questions
>   are considered to be "research-level" roughly when they can be
>   discussed between two professors or between two graduate students
>   working on Ph.D.'s, but not usually between a professor and a typical
>   undergraduate student. It does not include questions at the level of
>   difficulty of typical undergraduate course/textbook homework/exercise.
>
> What do you mean by "theoretical computer science"?
>
> For an explanation of what TCS is, we refer you to the description of
>   ACM Special Interest Group on Algorithms and Computation Theory
>   (SIGACT):
>
> > TCS covers a wide variety of topics including algorithms, data
> >     structures, computational complexity, parallel and distributed
> >     computation, probabilistic computation, quantum computation, automata
> >     theory, information theory, cryptography, program semantics and
> >     verification, machine learning, computational biology, computational
> >     economics, computational geometry, and computational number theory and
> >     algebra.
>
> Work in this field is often distinguished by its emphasis on
>   mathematical technique and rigor.